Tailwind CSS and Next.js: Local Images Not Rendering with Pseudo Elements
I'm working on a project using Tailwind CSS and Next.js. Despite extensive research, I've encountered an issue I can't resolve.
The Problem:
I am trying to use pseudo-elements ::before and ::after to render two local images. However, the images do not display on the screen. Interestingly, the images load correctly when I use URLs from the internet.
This is my code inside my tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}", "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            content: {
                lianeG: 'url("/assets/images/lianeG.svg")',
                lianeD: 'url("/assets/images/lianeD.svg")',
            },
            // URL from internet -> it works.
            // content: {
            //     lianeG: 'url("https://picsum.photos/100")',
            //     lianeD: 'url("https://picsum.photos/100")',
            // },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};

The code from header.js
import Image from "next/image";
import bouncyMoki from "../assets/images/bouncyMoki.svg";

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="relative before:content-lianeG after:content-lianeD before:absolute before:top-0 before:left-0 after:absolute after:top-0 after:right-0 after:inline-block after:size-40">
            <div className="flex justify-around p-5 bg-[#F5F3E2]">
                <Image src={bouncyMoki} className="size-12 animate-bouncy-move" alt="Bouncy Moki" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <nav className="bg-[#276B4D] mx-auto m-5 p-2 font-poppins font-medium text-white">
                    <ul className="flex justify-around">
                        <li className="p-5">
                            <a href="#monkeysGif ">Monkeys Gifs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="p-5">
                            <a href="#trendyGif">Trending Gifs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li className="p-5">
                            <a href="#fishesGif">Fishes Gifs</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

In my terminal this message pop when i reload my page :
GET /assets/images/lianeG.svg 404 in 16ms
GET /assets/images/lianeD.svg 404 in 14ms

Additional Information:

::before and ::after  element are created in the HTML as expected, but they are not displaying my images from my local folder.

I've tried various paths to ensure the images are correctly referenced and a lot of stuff i've found on internet without succes. If the path isn't correct there is an error message anyway.

I've tried to create it inside Global.css file, same thing, ::before
and ::after element are created in the HTML, but they are not
displaying my images.


As you can see, they're created on my html :
HTML Render with inspect element
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)
Update : Thanks to : Karson Jo who found the solution :

The SVG that you can't display is being loaded in CSS, so it shouldn't be related to the import. However, this method should only recognize files in the public folder. Also, the path should be written as a relative path. For example, if your file is public/sub/pic.svg, then it should be 'url("/sub/pic.svg")'

Yes, i had deleted the public folder when i created my Next App. Now it works like a charm after recreating it as Karson Jo explained.

/asseSts ? Isn't it just a typo ?

Not a typo.. even if i misspelled Assets, all the path were ok on my VS CODE. And I've changed the whole thing by removing the extra “S”, but it just doesn't work.

Have you tried to define it outside tailwind in plain CSS to check what is going on ?

Normally webpack shouldn't be able to handle the import of svg, do you have svgr installed? Also, could you please provide your next.config.js file?

Yes, i tried to create it inside Global.css file, same thing, ::before and ::after element are created in the HTML as expected, but they are not displaying my images.

No I don't have svgr installed.
I updated my post with the next.config.mjs.I don't know why it's in MJS format and not JS.

The SVG that you can't display is being loaded in CSS, so it shouldn't be related to the import. However, this method should only recognize files in the public folder. Also, the path should be written as a relative path. For example, if your file is public/sub/pic.svg, then it should be 'url("/sub/pic.svg")'.

Thanks a lot. I'm kinda still new to all of this and i deleted the public folder... i tried to recreate and it works as you explained !!   You're the best !

You're welcome.
